# In karate DSL how do i call javascript function in the 'Then' statement

Tags: javascript, karate

I have written a JavaScript function but i'm unable to call it in the 'Then' statement of my request. I need the syntax to call a JavaScript function in the same

```
Background: 
* def randomPhoneString = function(list) {  var rand = Math.random();  Math.floor(rand * 100000000);}

Scenario: Get list 
Given path '/example/test'  
When method get 
Then status 200
Then def resp = response.list
Then def List = randomPhoneString(resp)
```

Not a great example but it would be a usecase like this.
The error I'm getting is : 
**javascript evaluation failed: randomPhoneString(list)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your example is terrible :P it is still not clear what you are trying to do. I just tried this and it worked:

```
* def randomPhoneString = function() { var rand = Math.random(); return Math.floor(rand * 100000000) + '' }
* def temp = randomPhoneString()
* print temp
```

It printed:

```
[print] 59303272
```